# JQuery overrides checkbox functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a web app, and one of it's aspects is a to do list. The problem with the todo list is that when I click the checkbox, it doesn't get checked. I researched a bit and found that `jQuery` basically overrides the click event necessary to display the checkbox as checked. However, I've tried various solutions throughout the web, yet none seem to resolve the issue of the unchecked checkbox.

I've reproduced the problem below:

```js
function updateItemStatus() {
 var me = this; 
 console.log(me);
}

function addNewItem(list,itemText){
 var listItem = document.createElement("li");
 
 var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
 checkBox.type = "checkbox";
 checkBox.onclick = updateItemStatus;
 
 var span = document.createElement("span");
 span.innerText = itemText;
 
 listItem.appendChild(checkBox);
 listItem.appendChild(span);
 
 
 list.appendChild(listItem);
}

//$("input[type="checkbox"]").change(function() {
//if(this.checked) {
//Do stuff
//}
//});


inItemText.onkeyup = function(event) {
 
 
 var totalItems = 0;
 var inItemText = document.getElementById("inItemText");
 var itemText = event.which;
 
 // Event.which (13) = ENTER
 // ONLY proceed if key up = ENTER
 if(event.which == 13){
  var itemText = inItemText.value;
  if (itemText == "" || itemText == " "){
   return false;
  } 
  addNewItem(document.getElementById("todoList"),itemText); 
  
  inItemText.focus();
  inItemText.select();
  
  
  }
 }
```

```css
body{
 padding:120px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]{   
opacity:1 !important;
}

li span {
 padding:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
 

  
  Press Enter to add an item.
  <p><input type = "text" id = "inItemText" /> </p>
  
  <ul id = "todoList">
   
   </ul>
```

For reference, here is the link: https://codepen.io/Refath/pen/LdBbQV?editors=1010

Comment: *"When I click the checkbox, it doesn't become checked. I researched a bit and found that JQuery basically overirdes the click event nesscary to display the checkbox as checked"* No, it doesn't. Not by default, anyway.

Comment: The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: OK, Thank you @T.J.Crowder, I'll fix my question.

Comment: I've edited my question with a SO Snippet.

Comment: When I run the snippet, I don't see any checkboxes. All I see is a line and a New Item button. Pressing that button doesn't do anything. Please review the MCVE link above again: Your snippet should *demonstrate the problem*.

Comment: I should have noted that to add a list item, one should press enter, **not** click the New Item button. Sorry fort he confusion.

Comment: @DiViHart Please add complete code.

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra I have, please check the edit.

Comment: @DiViHart I found the solution you need, check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inspected your code and found that `pointer-events: none;` is blocking your checkboxes to be clickable / changable.

Add the following line to your `css`: `pointer-events: all;`

```
input[type="checkbox"]{   
    opacity:1 !important;
    pointer-events: all !important;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: @DiViHart: These sorts of precedence games shouldn't be necessary, I suggest going back to the Materialize site and seeing what examples they provide for correctly rendering usable checkboxes, as they are presumably disabling clicks for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with jQuery, it's two *other* aspects of your page taht are each independently causing this:

1. Materialize has a rule explicitly disallowing clicks on checkboxes:

   ```
   [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked), [type="checkbox"]:checked {
       position: absolute;
       opacity: 0;
       pointer-events: none;
   }
   ```

   `pointer-events: none` means it doesn't receive clicks.
2. After removing Materialize, your rule giving the `span` padding makes the `span` overlap the checkbox, and so we end up clicking the span, not the checkbox.

If I remove materialize and your padding rule, it solves the problem:

```js
function updateItemStatus() {
 var me = this; 
 console.log(me);
}

function addNewItem(list,itemText){
 var listItem = document.createElement("li");
 
 var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
 checkBox.type = "checkbox";
 checkBox.onclick = updateItemStatus;
 
 var span = document.createElement("span");
 span.innerText = itemText;
 
 listItem.appendChild(checkBox);
 listItem.appendChild(span);
 
 
 list.appendChild(listItem);
}

//$("input[type="checkbox"]").change(function() {
//if(this.checked) {
//Do stuff
//}
//});


inItemText.onkeyup = function(event) {
 
 
 var totalItems = 0;
 var inItemText = document.getElementById("inItemText");
 var itemText = event.which;
 
 // Event.which (13) = ENTER
 // ONLY proceed if key up = ENTER
 if(event.which == 13){
  var itemText = inItemText.value;
  if (itemText == "" || itemText == " "){
   return false;
  } 
  addNewItem(document.getElementById("todoList"),itemText); 
  
  inItemText.focus();
  inItemText.select();
  
  
  }
 }
```

```css
body{
 padding:120px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]{   
opacity:1 !important;
}

/*
li span {
 padding:50px;
}
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
-->

  
  Press Enter to add an item.
  <p><input type = "text" id = "inItemText" /> </p>
  
  <ul id = "todoList">
   
   </ul>
```

Presumably there are examples of how to correctly render usable checkboxes with Materialize on their website; I've never used it.